# How do you display the latest single entry from row and single Column using Swift Code

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I am able to get to this point, and not sure how to print the result of the latest entry. I've a class called "Transaction" and multiple column, and hundreds of rows that is entered in different date and time. I'm only interested to display the latest entry from the class. Please help if you have any idea. thanks.

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Transaction")
query.whereKey("city", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
query.limit = 1
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
if error == nil{
   print ("Well Done!)
}
else{
  print("too bad, something went wrong!")
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get access to the objects that are returned, you can do this:

```
if error == nil {
    let foundObjects: [PFObject] = objects!
    for object in foundObjects {
        print(object["city"])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and it gives me error message "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value. and I added ! the end of City and PFObject and still the same error, any idea?

Comment: Well I was just guessing that that was one of the columns of your `PFObject` based on your query but that makes it sound like such a column doesn't exist. You could just `print(object)` and see if it has the data you expect it to.

Comment: it prints all the cities, and remember, I'm only interested to print the latest entry from the column called "city"

Comment: I don't think I understand. You're setting the query limit to one so it should only return one object, but you're saying it's "printing all the cities" so I don't see how this could be.

Comment: if you looked at the original code I specified query.limit 1 query.orderByDescending("createdAt"). I'm not interested to print all of the results out, only one specific row with one column.. I hope this can help, let me know if I can give you more info...

Comment: I know you set the limit to one, that's why I don't understand how you can say "it prints all the cities" because it should only print one based on that limit. What does your Parse class look like?

Comment: I'm unable to attach the table, may be because I don't know how... but this is what it look like, I've the columns as follow "city" "state" "zipcode" and so on, and city is set as string, and have over 30 rows... On the previous example it prints out all cities.

Comment: So your one PFObject as multiple cities?

Comment: No, let's say A1, A2, A3.. and a1 is the intersection of columnA and row 1, so this A1 has only one city..

Comment: Hey Pbush25, Thanks, and this what the trick, it prints all the cities on the screen, but it displays one city on the next label field I want it to be. So, basically it works... and thanks again.